Walk me through wifi time machine to old mac (or is it a bad idea?)
I'm a very mobile worker, constantly going out and about to work from cafes etc. This makes it really hard to do normal time machine backups, as I'll tend to often be about to pick up my laptop to go off somewhere and some work done, but, whoops, I can't go because it's in the middle of backing up and it takes forever to either finish or cancel and eject the drive.  This drives me nuts.
So I'm thinking of switching to a wireless solution with the next machine. Right now I'm using a 2019 intel MBP, and I'm about to buy a new M4.  I was going to trade in the old one, but ... what if I can use it/the drive connected to it as a time machine backup target over wi-fi instead?
So I'd like to set something up where basically there's a big SSD connected to my old machine, and it's on wi-fi, and then whenever it sees the new machine on the network it starts a backup.
Does this work/is this possible?  Or do I need to have the old machine directly plugged into ethernet/the router?  (Which would be challenging.)  If it matters, I use an old google mesh system, on top of a cable modem, and I know nothing about networking...
Thank you!

Time Machine works best with a stable connection to the drive it backs up to. You may want to look at Backblaze or Arq instead.

Use directly attached SSD for backup - this is the fastest and most reliable way of using Time Machine.

No, don’t do this.
Network backups are usually 5x or more slower so if you can’t find time when a direct attached backup will complete - the interruptions will make it very unlikely you can have a coherent backup.
With the new hardware, you should have very good data on how long a backup to the SSD takes and then can decide if the slowdown on network backup will help you. Why not let a portable machine backup each night to attached storage when it charges?
While you are testing network, remember you can use thunderbolt point to point networking to get the first big backup done.

https://eclecticlight.co/2024/11/12/migrating-to-a-new-mac-and-claiming-time-machine-backups/
https://eclecticlight.co/consolation-t2m2-and-log-utilities/

Absolutely get T2M2 on all your Macs to enjoy the timing and checks to make measured changes and optimize your experience. Hopefully you can isolate a problematic folder or large file that changes often and get Time Machine to take 10 to 15 minutes and then go fully networked over WiFi.

heh, thanks, maybe I'll just drop a wad on a samsung t9 or something and see how much speed I can squeeze out of it

Yes, you can setup your old Mac to be a "Time Machine server" to other Macs on the network.
In System Settings > General > Sharing, turn on File Sharing, and click on the little "info" i symbol. Add the disk, and right-click on the disk to reveal "Advanced Options".

The Advanced Options dialog contains a checkbox to "Share as a Time Machine backup destination". There are other options, including limits per user on backup size.
You may have/want to create users in the Sharing dialog (as shown) that can access the disk.
As said, backups will be slow, so make sure there is time for the initial backup to complete -- let it run all night. Then incremental backups should not take too long.
Other options are dedicated NAS hardware; or use some syncing software to keep the two Macs' files synchronised. (Not quite the same as a backup, of course, because no versioning nor deletion recovery.)
